# Memory leak when allocating strings as struct members

Tags: c, string, data-structures, struct, memory-leaks

I have built a function to insert a node into a doubly-linked list. The structure includes 2 strings, for which I am dynamically allocating space inside the function. According to Valgrind, this causes a memory leak. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
typedef struct Node {
    char *str1, *str2;
    Node *next, *prev;
};

void add(Node* list, char* string1, char* string2) {         
   Node* temp = list;
   Node* new_node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
   if (!new_node) return;

   new_node->str1 = (char*) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
   new_node->str2 = (char*) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
   strcpy(new_player->str1, string1);
   strcpy(new_player->str2, string2);

   if (!temp) {
      temp = new_node;
      new_node->prev = new_node->next = NULL;
      new_node = NULL;
      free(new_node);
      return;
   } else {
       while (temp->next) temp = temp->next;

       new_node->prev = temp;
       new_node->next = NULL;
       temp->next =new_node;

       new_node = NULL;
       free(new_node);
   }

   void destroy(Node* list) {
      Node* temp;
      while (list) {
         temp = list->next;
         free(list->str1); 
         free(list->str2);
         free(list); 
         list = temp;
      }  
  }
```

I am using the destroy function inside of main() after having finished working with the list. Is that not enough? Am I supposed to somehow free the strings inside the add function?

I am using this function repeatedly in my program so it causes a loss of around 10.0000 bytes. Can you please tell me why this memory leak occurs and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: The only time you'd want to `free` something in the 'add' function is to clean up an incompletely allocated node when an error occurs.

Comment: How do you initialize the list? Post your `main` function as well (i.e., post a [mcve]!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `add` function `malloc`s a `Node`, links it into the list and then `free`s the allocated `Node` for some reason.  That will leave dangling pointers in the list.

Your `add` function also has no mechanism to add the first `Node` to an empty list.  There are two ways that you could do that.  The first way is to return a pointer to the first node of the list:

```
Node* add(Node* list, char* string1, char* string2) {         
    Node* temp = list;
    Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (!new_node) return NULL;

    new_node->str1 = malloc(strlen(string1)+1);
    new_node->str2 = malloc(strlen(string2)+1);
    if (!new_node->str1 || !new_node->str2) {
        // allocation error for one of the strings
        free(new_node->str1);
        free(new_node->str2);
        free(new_node);
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy(new_node->str1, string1);
    strcpy(new_node->str2, string2);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (!temp) {
        new_node->prev = NULL;
        list = new_node;
    } else {
        while (temp->next) temp = temp->next;

        new_node->prev = temp;
        temp->next = new_node;
    }

    // return pointer to first node
    return list;
}
```

Example call using the first way:

```
Node* mylist = NULL;
...
mylist = add(mylist, "hello", "world");
```

The second way is to change the first parameter to a pointer to a pointer to the start of the list:

```
void add(Node** list, char* string1, char* string2) {         
    Node* temp = *list;
    Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (!new_node) return;

    new_node->str1 = malloc(strlen(string1)+1);
    new_node->str2 = malloc(strlen(string2)+1);
    if (!new_node->str1 || !new_node->str2) {
        // allocation error for one of the strings
        free(new_node->str1);
        free(new_node->str2);
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }

    strcpy(new_node->str1, string1);
    strcpy(new_node->str2, string2);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (!temp) {
        new_node->prev = NULL;
        *list = new_node;
    } else {
        while (temp->next) temp = temp->next;

        new_node->prev = temp;
        temp->next = new_node;
    }
}
```

Example call using the second way:

```
Node* mylist = NULL;
...
add(&mylist, "hello", "world");
```